# How can I make a <select> dropdown in AngularJS default to a value in localstorage?

Tags: angularjs

I have a `<select>` that I am populating with a list of values. Everything works and I see the expected list. But now I would like to have the value set to a locally stored value if available.

I have the code below. When I run this code the number after the Type in the label changes to match that in the localstorage but the select box does not change.

```
getContentTypeSelect: function ($scope) {
    entityService.getEntities('ContentType')
        .then(function (result) {
            $scope.option.contentTypes = result;
            $scope.option.contentTypesPlus = [{ id: 0, name: '*' }].concat(result);
            $scope.option.selectedContentType 
                 = localStorageService.get('selectedContentType');
        }, function (result) {
            alert("Error: No data returned");
        });
},

<span class="label">Type {{ option.selectedContentType }}</span>
   <select
       data-ng-disabled="!option.selectedSubject"
       data-ng-model="option.selectedContentType"
       data-ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in option.contentTypesPlus">
       <option style="display: none" value="">Select Content Type</option>
   </select>
```

Here is the code I have that sets the value in localstorage:

```
    $scope.$watch('option.selectedContentType', function () {
        if ($scope.option.selectedContentType != null) {
            localStorageService.add('selectedContentType', 
                 $scope.option.selectedContentType);
            $scope.grid.data = null;
            $scope.grid.selected = false;
        }
    });
```

Here is the data stored in contentTypesPlus:

```
0: Object
id: 0
name: "*"
__proto__: Object
1: b
id: 1
name: "Page"
__proto__: b
2: b
id: 2
name: "Menu"
__proto__: b
3: b
id: 3
name: "Content Block"
__proto__: b
```

How can I make the select box go to the localstorage value if there is one?

**Update**

Still hoping for an answer and I would be happy to accept another if some person can help me. The answer given is not complete and I am still waiting for more information. I am hoping someone can give me an example that fits with my code. Thanks

Comment: I guess you need to set the selectedContentType as the scope variable.
$scope.option.selectedContentType = localStorageService.get('selectedContentType');

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo. I was setting that correctly in my code but missed it out here. Still does not work when set like you mention.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make sure `selectedContentType` needs to be the `id` field of the option object according to the comprehension expression defined in the select directive.

The comprehensive expression is defined as

```
item.id as item.name for item in option.contentTypesPlus
```

`item.id` will be the actual value stored in the `ng-model` `option.selectedContentType`

Comment: Yes that was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out. Can you explain what you mean by "selectedContentType needs to be the id field of the option object ". If you could give me an example that would be really good. Sorry I don't understand. Thanks

Comment: Thanks but how can I do this with my code? I have <option value="1">Page</option> for example. I am not sure at all what you mean and how I can modify my code to make it do as you say.

Comment: sza means that if the value from the localStorage matches an id from the `contentTypesPlus` array then angular will set it as the default (see http://jsfiddle.net/8cpJ2/1/). What value is returned from your localStorage?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I updated the question with the code that is used to set the localstorage. The values there are 0,1,2 .. 3 etc. These do match the values in the contentTypesPlus array but it still does not correctly change the value.

Comment: I think the problem is that the value coming out of the localStorage is returned as a string, not an integer. Try `$scope.option.selectedContentType = parseInt(localStorageService.get('selectedContentType'));`

Comment: @jonnyynnoj - I think this solves the problem. I will some more tests and update the thread later. My first test seemed to work but I want to be sure. If I can confirm it solves the problem can you make this into an answer so I can accept it and so it will be clear to others. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Say this is your select with ng-model

```
<select 
    ng-model="language.selected" 
    ng-init="language.selected = settings.language[settings.language.selected.id]" 
    ng-options="l.label for l in settings.language" 
    ng-change="updateLanguage(language.selected)">
```

In your controller

```
$scope.settings = {
enableEventsNotification: true,
enableiBeaconNotification: true,
hours: [
    { id: 0, label: '3h', value: 3 },
    { id: 1, label: '6h', value: 6 },
    { id: 2, label: '9h', value: 9 },
    { id: 3, label: '12h', value: 12 },
    { id: 4, label: '24h', value: 24 }
  ],
language: [
    { id: 0, label: 'English', value: 'en-us' },
    { id: 1, label: 'Francais', value: 'fr-fr' }
  ] 
};
$scope.hours = [];
$scope.hours.selected = $localstorage.getObject('hours',   $scope.settings.hours[1]);
$scope.settings.hours.selected = $localstorage.getObject('hours', $scope.settings.hours[1]);
$scope.hours.selected = $scope.hours.selected;
```